# Convert two objects into one array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 JS(json) obects with identical keys:

```
{"id1" : "some1", "id2" : "some2", "id3" : "some3"}
{"id1" : "another1", "id2" : "another2", "id3" : "another3"}
```

I need to convert it into

```
[
    {
        "id" : "id1",
        "some" : "some1",
        "another" : "another1"
    },
    {
        "id" : "id2",
        "some" : "some2",
        "another" : "another2"
    },
    {
        "id" : "id3",
        "some" : "some3",
        "another" : "another3"
    }
]
```

So, this is the question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yTSDw/) you go:

```
var some = {"id1" : "some1", "id2" : "some2", "id3" : "some3"};
var another = {"id1" : "another1", "id2" : "another2", "id3" : "another3"};

var result = [];
for (var id in some) {
    result.push({
        id: id,
        some: some[id],
        another: another[id]
    });
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: @PabloKarlsson Yup, no problem. JavaScript does not evaluate object keys, but does evaluate object values.

Comment: can you please elaborate it logic ..i didnt get it .

Comment: i have added a new key named "name" : "avinash" but it didnt display

Comment: @AvinashBabu What logic? Iterate over the keys of `some`, create result objects to hold the key and corresponding values from `some` and `another`, and add the result objects to an array. Note that the question states that the keys in both objects are identical.

Comment: how can we add if the keys are different ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu I'm sorry, you'll have to create a new question for this.  It's too broad to answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This should work provided each id exists in each hash.

```
var ids = {"id1" : "some1", "id2" : "some2", "id3" : "some3"};
var ids2 = {"id1" : "another1", "id2" : "another2", "id3" : "another3"};
a= [];
for (var id in ids) {
  a.push({id: id, some:ids[id], another : ids2[id]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to double push if you have a little object like that

```js
const ob1 = {
  "id1": "some1",
  "id2": "some2",
  "id3": "some3"
}
const ob2 = {
  "id1": "another1",
  "id2": "another2",
  "id3": "another3"
}
let array = []
array.push(ob1)
array.push(ob2)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: It's definitely not what OP wants...